# How to call a method which takes a closure as a parameter in Swfit?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to write a method as below:

```
class ThisIsExample{
    func theMethod(inside:((Error?)->Void)->Void){        
       //some implementation
    }       
}
```

But, when I try to call this method, I don't know how to do that.

I wrote code below:

```
let example = ThisIsExample()
example.theMethod { ({(err) in }) in
        print("print something")
}
```

I try to write another closure, which is   { (err) in }  inside the closure

But it is not workable, I'll receive error message like

> Contextual closure type '((Error?) -> Void) -> Void' expects 1
>   argument, but 0 were used in closure body

So...could anyone please teach me how to call this method in correct way, thank you so much.

Comment: Please explain what your closure is for. What are you trying to accomplish? Your closure definition is unusually complicated.

Comment: Hi @Mke Taverne, actually, I'm working on an old project which was written in obj-c and now I'm developing new features based on the codebase using Swift. So, there is one of the method which looks like what I post, and I don't know how to call this method. That's why i'm asking this question

Comment: @uzoo Show the obj-c equivalent code. Your question has a straightforward answer right now but it doesn't look like a good approach. Lets see an alternative or shall I post an answer for the current context?

Answer (score 2):

Although not sure what is the purpose of nested closure. But if you want to use this approach then you should call the closure in this way,

```
example.theMethod { (closure) in      
     closure(NSError.init())
}
```

Comment: You should use Error instead of NSError. And you should pass whatever value is appropriate: nil if theMethod was successful, or an instance of Error if theMethod was not successful.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Yes, `NSError` conforms to `Error` so i don't see any issue to use it. But offCourse he should pass the relevant error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this:

```
 func theMethod(inside:(Error?) -> ()) {
        print("Closure as paramater")
    }
```

This will take Error as closure parameter and return void.

you can call this function as below:

```
 theMethod { (error) in

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something Like This

```
class NewClass
{
    class func myCustomFunc(_ parameter1: String, parameterDict : [String : AnyObject]?, success:@escaping (String) -> Void, failure:@escaping (String) -> Void)
    {

        /// Just example Bool
        var result : Bool = false

        /// Get the parameter you sent while calling this Clousure block
        let myParamString = parameter1
        let paramDict = parameterDict

        /// Share the output in case of Success and Failure
        if (result){
            success("success")
        }
        else{
            failure("Failure")
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
NewClass.myCustomFunc("demoStr", parameterDict: [:], success: { (succesString) in
            if succesString == "success"{

            }
        }) { (failureStr) in
            if failureStr == "failure"{

            }
        }
```

This Function Accepts Parameter and Also give Different blocks depend upon closures